# Passing ordered listbox selections to a string array

Tags: vba

I've got a multi-select listbox called CV with several options on it. I need a sub that captures the users choices on the listbox that is ordered inside of an array. For example, if someone selected option 2 and then option 1, the array should be: (option 2, option 1)

I've been using this code to try and capture these selections. CV being the listbox and CVSelections being the array. It is capturing the choices, but not in the order I select them. Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Sub CV_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0

    For i = 0 To CV.ListCount - 1
        If CV.Selected(i) Then
            If Count = 0 Then
                ReDim CVSelections(Count)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve CVSelections(Count)
            End If
            CVSelections(Count) = CV.List(i)
            'MsgBox (CVSelections(Count))
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A listbox does not track the order in which you select them, only that they are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Listbox` does not inherently "remember" the order of user selections, but you can track it using a module-scope dictionary.

`objDic.keys` return an array with ordered user selections.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim objDic As Object
Private Sub CV_Change()
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    For i = 0 To CV.ListCount - 1
        sKey = CV.List(i)
        If CV.Selected(i) Then
            If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = ""
            End If
        Else
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then objDic.Remove sKey
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Me.CV.AddItem CStr(i)
    Next
    Me.CV.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Join(objDic.keys, ",")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Great code. I particularly like your answer as the similar questions required two list boxes while this is nice and simple.